# Wrapping material UI button and props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For consistency reasons sometimes I wrap simple components like material UI's `<Button>`

```
import { Button, ButtonProps } from '@material-ui/core';
export const MainButton = ({...props}: ButtonProps) => {
   return <Button color="secondary" variant="contained" {...props}></Button>
}
```

But I noticed I cannot use this to pass `rel` prop even though `Button` accepts it

Can do this

```
<Button rel="noopener"></Button>
```

But not this, as it does not recognize `rel`  (cannot use `rel`, `target`, etc, any `a` attributes)

```
<MainButton onClick={onclick} disabled={true} rel="noopener"/>
```

I saw this https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/12212 but cannot figure out more details from it. Is `ButtonProps` not actually the correct props?

Comment: Why is props being deconstructed in the component? ({...props}: ButtonProps)

Comment: I have more non standard props but didn't add them to keep this simple

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is extend the ButtonProps type into a new interface and use that to define your new prop type. You can add any prop you want to this new interface and have access to it. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customprops-qj6b53?file=/src/CustomButton.tsx:0-261)

Here is the App file showing the implementation of the CustomButton Component:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <CustomButton
        myTitle="Example"
        rel="noopener"
        onClick={() => alert("Example showing other props works")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the CustomButton Component:

```
import { Button, ButtonProps } from "@material-ui/core";

interface CustomButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  myTitle: string;
  rel: string;
}

export const CustomButton = (props: CustomButtonProps) => {
  return <Button {...props}>{props.myTitle}</Button>;
};
```

Comment: The problem is that `rel` and other props are already allowed on `Button` but are not part of `ButtonProps`

Comment: Yes? This expands the type of button props and allows you to pass any prop you want to the Button.

Comment: mui's `Button` already accepts `rel` etc. The question is why does `ButtonProps` not include `rel` etc.